# How to write test that mocks the $route.replace in vue components

Tags: vue.js, replace, routes, jestjs

I created a vue.js project by Vue CLI 3 with Router.
And I have a component (vue file) that contains statements this.$route.replae.

```
        this.$router.replace({
          name: "secure"
        });
```

I wrote a unit test for the component and found an error when running test:unit:

```
        Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined]
```

how should I mock the $router and pass the test?

Comment: Please include your test code.

Comment: How to include the test code？It tells me too long when I copied my test code here.